# adding custom animation class to jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-animations, animate.css

I have created a custom animation class in CSS which I am dynamically adding to an element using jQuery. My custom animation class begins once an animate.css animation has completed.

The issue I am having is my custom animation is not playing, and for the life of me I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I can see in dev tools that the class is being added to my element but the animation is not occurring.

custom-fade css:

```
.custom-fade{
    -webkit-animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom;
    animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom;
}

@keyframes custom{
    0% { opacity:.5; }
    66% { opacity:.2; }
    100% { opacity:0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes custom{
    0% { opacity: .5; }
    66% { opacity: .2; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes custom{
    0% { opacity: .5; }
    66% { opacity: .2; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

jQuery:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
var fadeInUp = 'animated fadeIn fadeInUp';
var fadeOut = 'animated fadeOut';
var customFade = '.custom-fade';

$('.bg-img').addClass(fadeInUp);

    $('.bg-img').one( animationEnd, function(){
        $(this).removeClass(fadeInUp).addClass('.custom-fade');
    });
```

Comment: Did you intentionally place 'one' for attaching the event handler? $('.bg-img').one(...)

Comment: @eeya I think that is a typo. He wanted to write `$('.bg-img').on(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in **adding class**. You should give `'custom-fade'` instead of `'.custom-fade'` in `addClass()`.

**Sample Code**:

```js
jQuery:

var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
var fadeInUp = 'animated fadeIn fadeInUp';
var fadeOut = 'animated fadeOut';
var customFade = '.custom-fade';

$('.bg-img').addClass(fadeInUp);

    $('.bg-img').on( animationEnd, function(){
        $(this).removeClass(fadeInUp).addClass('custom-fade');
    });
```

```css
.custom-fade{
    -webkit-animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom;
    animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom;
}

@keyframes custom{
    0% { opacity:.5; }
    66% { opacity:.2; }
    100% { opacity:0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes custom{
    0% { opacity: .5; }
    66% { opacity: .2; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes custom{
    0% { opacity: .5; }
    66% { opacity: .2; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.bg-img{
width:200px;
height:500px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```